# Как добавлять значения с определённой строки?

Tags: python

Имеется следующая проблема: есть выгрузка порядка 800строк, знаю, что до 550 строки идёт 2019 год, а после 550 строки 2020. В датафрейме изначально не было столбца с годами, требуется добавить года. Собственно вопрос, как добавлять значения до определённой строки? Задача вроде простая, но не знаю как реализовать задуманное. Думаю сделать так, но везде выводит 2020

```
def col_year(year):
    if len(str(df)) <550:
        normal_year= str(year) + '19'
    else:
        normal_year = str(year) + '20’
    return str(normal_year)
```

Может быть найти один определенный индекс и от него изменять все? Прошу помощи!

Comment: `len(str(df)) <550` - а что вы вот так проверяете вообще, что это за странное условие? Да и в целом код непонятный, откуда берётся `2021`, из вашего кода  такое значение никогда не получится.

Comment: опечатка, 2020 выходит. Ну, т.о. пытаюсь задать если длина меньше 550, то вывод 2019 год, если больше 2020 год

Comment: Длина чего меньше? Вы смотрели, что выдаёт `str(df)` вообще? Тут что-то типа `df.iloc[:550]` нужно, ваш код что-то непонятное делает.

Comment: Если он делает что то непонятное, то как сделать понятное? Мне нужно до 550 строки сделать столбец со значением  2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поидее вам нужно просто список с годами, первые 550 элементов списка со значением *2019*, остальные 250 - *2020*

```py
col_year = ['2019']*550 + ['2020']*250
```

И затем добавить его в DataFrame

```
df['col_year'] = col_year
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!! Никогда бы не додумался так сделать. Ещё раз большое спасибо!